# Delete "views" in Cloudant to make space

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I am currently using the Lite version of Cloudant and I have reached the 1GB limit that is offered.
I tried to delete some data but as you can see in the picture below, the actual data in my database is not very heavy.
Most of the space seems to be taken up by views. Does anyone know what this represents and how we can get rid of them such that I can make some space in the database?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views are secondary indexes generated by map and reduce functions in your design documents. They may have been created by a developer directly, or behind your back if you are using an application such as NodeRed. If you delete a design document, the associated index should be removed, but this may of course affect the functionality of whatever it is using your Cloudant database.

Removing views WILL break any application expecting to find them there. Think **carefully** if this is really what you want to do. You should think about backing up your data first (https://github.com/cloudant/couchbackup).

Views are stored in design documents. They are documents where the id starts with `_design`. You can list design docs using `curl`:

```
% curl 'https://USER:PASS@USER.cloudant.com/DATABASE_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"'
{"total_rows":8747,"offset":5352,"rows":[
    {"id":"_design/names","key":"_design/names","value":{"rev":"1-4b72567e275bec45a1e37562a707e363"}},
    {"id":"_design/queries","key":"_design/queries","value":{"rev":"7-7e128fa652e9a1942fb8a01f07ec497c"}},
    {"id":"_design/routeid","key":"_design/routeid","value":{"rev":"1-a04ab1fc814ac1eaa0b445aece032945"}},
    {"id":"_design/setters","key":"_design/setters","value":{"rev":"1-7bf0fc0255244248de4f89a20ff730f4"}}
]}
```

You can then delete those with a `curl -XDELETE ...` -- or you can do it via the Cloudant dashboard.

Comment: The data is coming from a device similar to the TI sensortag. Is there a way to prevent cloudant from storing these views?

Comment: I was able to find where views are stored and how they can be deleted, but me question remains. in what way could deleting them affect the functionality?  I am using it to store device events that record various things such as temperature and pressure. The database is used to make historical charts of the data

Comment: Let's say that an application (most will) expects to be able to look up data based on other things than the document id. That requires a view. Think of views as the way to implement indexes, joins and queries. Out of the box, a Cloudant db can only look up docs based on doc id.